# Binding an Image using XAML and ImageSource

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp

I have a media player element that uses a `PosterSource` (like `ImageSource`) for a UWP application I am working on. The code looks like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="MainMPE" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" AutoPlay="True" PosterSource="{Binding PosterSource}">
    </MediaPlayerElement>
</Grid>
```

In my code I have the following setup for `PosterSource`

```
public sealed partial class PlayerView : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ImageSource _PosterSource;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ImageSource PosterSource
    {
        get => _PosterSource;
        set
        {
            if (_PosterSource != value)
            {
                _PosterSource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PosterSource));
            }
        }
    }

    private async void PlayerView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await SetPoster();
        // other code to load PlayerView
    }

    private async Task SetPoster()
    {
        var tempBitamp = new BitmapImage();
        await tempBitamp.SetSourceAsync(/* Stream comes from anotehr object */);
        PosterSource = tempBitamp;
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My problem is that it doesn't update. The image never loads. If I call the *MainMPE.PosterSource* object directly from code and set it to my BitmapImage, it works, but I'm trying to get this to behave properly with Bindings. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I am missing from your code that could be an issue is setting the `DataContext` of your page. As opposed to `x:Bind` syntax, you need to set the "context" where your bindings should be taken from. So if you want to use `{Binding}` to your page's code-behind, you can add the following line right after `InitializeComponent` call in the page's constructor:

```
DataContext = this;
```

After that it should work as expected.

### Even better solution

UWP brought a better syntax for data-binding - `x:Bind`. The advatage of this bidning is that it gets rid of all the reflection that is going on behind `Binding` and is done at compile-time and in a strongly-typed fashion instead. Also, it does not take `DataContext` into consideration and binds directly to the page's code-behind. The only thing to watch out for is that by default, `x:Bind` is `OneTime` only, so you have to manually set it's mode to `OneWay` if you are going to update the bound property's value:

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="MainMPE"
        AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" 
        AutoPlay="True" 
        PosterSource="{x:Bind PosterSource, Mode=OneWay}">
</MediaPlayerElement>
```

### More alternatives for `Binding`

Just as a side-note, there are more ways to set the `DataContext`. You can also do it in page's XAML code:

```
<Page ... DataContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Or in conjunction with `x:Name`:

```
<Page ... x:Name="Page" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Page}">
```

Both ways will set the `DataContext` to the `Page` instance itself.

Comment: Thanks so much, Martin! I did read about x:Bind while researching my solution, but had the same issues due to not using Mode=OneWay. This solution worked perfectly!

Comment: Awesome :-), happy coding!